# Shiny-server looking for config file in wrong path

Tags: r, configuration, shiny-server

After our server being offline all weekend I'm trying to restart our shiny server. This is run on a mac, in the terminal I'm running

```
 sudo shiny-server start
```

but I'm getting a strange error

```
[2018-03-26 13:43:12.370] [INFO] shiny-server - Shiny Server v1.  5.  7.0 
(Node.js v6.10.3)
[2018-03-26 13:43:12.373] [INFO] shiny-server - Using config file 
"/Users/rgraves/start"
[2018-03-26 13:43:12.387] [ERROR] shiny-server - Error loading config: File 
"/Users/rgraves/start" does not exist
[2018-03-26 13:43:12.387] [INFO] shiny-server - Shutting down worker processes
```

Obviously this is telling me the config file doesn't exist, which is true in this location. It exists exactly where I would expect it to at

```
 /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf
```

Why would shiny server not be using the default location for the config file? and how can I change it back to what it was before?

Comment: try the commands here: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000393668-Shiny-Server-Start-and-Stop-Commands